# How to replace JSON key's value in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a mysql JSON column like:

```
column       value
data         [{ "report1": { "result": "5"}, "report2": {"result": "6"}, "report3": {"a": "4"}}, {"report1": { "result": "9"},"report4": {"details": "<b>We need to show the details here</b>"}, "report3": {"result": "5"}}]
```

another instance of data is:

```
[{ "report1": { "result": "5"}, "report2": {"result": "6"}, "report3": {"a": "4"}}, {"report1": { "result": "9"}, "report3": {"result": "5"},"report4": {"details": "<b>We need to show the details here</b>"}}]
```

In above record the key is present on 2nd index.

And in this:

```
[{ "report1": { "result": "5"}, "report2": {"result": "6"}, "report3": {"a": "4"}}, {"report1": { "result": "9"}, "report3": {"result": "5"}}]
```

The key is not present.

I need to replace `{"details": "<b>We need to show the details here</b>"}`, i.e. key `report4`'s value with just `[]`, I need now data in this report.

Actually, the logic for generating data have been changed from XML data to JSON for only that key, so, we need to replace it with a blank array, the target type now, without affecting the other data.

Is there any direct solution to that? I'm avoiding creating procedures here.

So, The Target data will be:

```
[{ "report1": { "result": "5"}, "report2": {"result": "6"}, "report3": {"a": "4"}}, {"report1": { "result": "9"},"report4": [], "report3": {"result": "5"}}]
```

And yes the keys in JSON are not consistent, means, a key may present in `next` or `previous` record in the `table` but may not present in `this` record.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: "And yes the keys in JSON are not consistent, means, a key may present in next record but may not present in this record." So why are you giving only one record as example data?

Comment: Can I ask @PraveenKumar what is not clear, I think I'm pretty clear on the problem, I don't have any other explanation to this.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Let me give you another record. Actually I canonly give examples not the readl data.

Comment: @yashbhardwaj My only question was if you wanted to do it in MySQL itself or using PHP or JavaScript, as that's what it's ultimately consumed upon.

Comment: What's the criteria for replacing the contents of a report? Is it if there's *only* a `details` key, or something else?

Comment: @SimonBrahan the `<b></b>` block is the criteria to find the target.

Comment: @RaymondNijland your approach looks very good

Comment: "your approach looks very good " thank you @jspcal i've made the decision to delete mine answer because the query is missing the proper filter so it only updates within the report4 key and i didn't had the time to find a more general query with the correct filter (might could have fix that with a delivered table and filter on the path with a LIKE %report4% filter) and also supporting multiple report4 keys within the JSON data which is also possible offcource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column should be of type [`JSON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html) to use MySQL's JSON features efficiently. Then use the [JSON modification functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html), such as [`JSON_REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-replace).

Since each value contains a JSON array whose size may not be known in advance, you can create a small utility function to modify each element in the array.

```
create function modify_json(val json)
returns json
deterministic
begin
    declare len int default json_length(val);
    declare i int default 0;

    while i < len do
        # Replace the report4 property of the i'th element with an empty list
        set val = json_replace(val, concat('$[', i, '].report4'), '[]');
        set i = i + 1;
    end while;

    return val;
end;
```

With your utility function, update the records:

```
update table set data = modify_json(data)
where json_contains_path(data, 'one', '$[*].report4');
```

The records containing at least one element with a `report4` property will be updated according to the `modify_json` function in this case. You could achieve the same thing with multiple update commands that operate on each index of the JSON array separately.

If the column can't be of type JSON for some reason, then you can allow MySQL to coerce the data or your program can marshall the string into a JSON object, modify the data, then serialize it to a string, and update the row.

Comment: yes @jspcal you got it right in the first impression. Thank you. But As I said the data json is not consistent, so, in case there is no `t` in a record will fail the query.

Comment: You're the only person with the answer right now thanks @jspcal, let me give it a try.

Comment: this is what I said:
`update test_data_json set data = JSON_REPLACE(data, '$[*].report4.details', '[]') Error Code: 3149. In this situation, path expressions may not contain the * and ** tokens. 0.972 sec`

Comment: this is my Test Table:
`create table test_data_json( data json) ;`
`insert into test_data_json values('[{ "report1": { "result": "5"}, "report2": {"result": "6"}, "report3": {"a": "4"}}, {"report1": { "result": "9"},"report4": {"details": "<b>We need to show the details here</b>"}, "report3": {"result": "5"}}]');`
`insert into test_data_json values('[{ "report1": { "result": "5"}, "report2": {"result": "6"}, "report3": {"a": "4"}}, {"report1": { "result": "9"}, "report3": {"result": "5"}}]');`

`update test_data_json set data = JSON_REPLACE(data, '$[*].report4.details', '[]');`

Comment: "The column should be of type JSON to use MySQL's JSON features" That's not true.. JSON_* functions can also work on VARCHAR or TEXT datatypes..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Using a string type would be *extremely* inefficient.